# How to make the stone pillar have a better light behaviour?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, lighting

I'd try to make a scene with some stone pillars in it, but for some reason, it looks a bit different between the original file and the scene file.

[image]

the single pillar with sunlight and point light

[image]
The whole scene with a sky texture, sunlight, and compositing glare high/low and sunbeam

Should I add a Fill Light, rim light, or other things?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  What is your desired outcome?  What exactly displeases you about what you currently have?

Comment: I expect the outcome as the first picture, to look more realistic. The second one is kinda fake and looks like some paper.